# Rails Scaffolded reference wont save due to mass-assign restriction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, scaffolding, sqlite3-ruby

I'm brand-spankin'-new to rails, so forgive me if this is a stupid question -- i simply cannot piece together enough answers to tell if i started incorrectly. Here goes.

1. i created everything related to my `Company` model with `rails g scaffold Company name:string description:text location_city:string location_state:string accounttype:references`
2. i created everything related to the `Accounttype` model with `rails g scaffold Accounttype id:primary_key name:string price:decimal`
3. my `Company` model therefore contains the following allowances:

   `belongs_to :accounttype`

   `attr_accessible :description, :location_city, :location_state, :name`
4. when i go to my scaffold-generated edit form for company, and enter data in those fields, it throws an error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: accounttype`
5. if I add `:accounttype` to `attr_accessible`, it throws `Accounttype(#70175254242100) expected, got String(#70175215042700)` with the following request params:

   `{"utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"oXm3cqo0jemKYFB5OGqn5ixXLSB+bH19/1RhPUu0ZHU=",
    "company"=>{"name"=>"Acme Corp",
    "description"=>"a",
    "location_city"=>"san diego",
    "location_state"=>"california",
    "accounttype"=>"1"},
    "commit"=>"Create Company"}`

So, is my problem that I used `:references` to link the two models? if that is OK that i used that, then what should I do to get creating/updating to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats on using learning rails! You will have to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Company` model in  order to assign attributes directly to the `Accounttype` model. Like so:

```
belongs_to :accounttype

accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounttype

attr_accessible :description, :location_city, :location_state, :name, :accounttypes_attributes
```

Notice since you are using attr_accessible you have to add `accounttypes_attributes`
Also, I would suggest changing `Accounttype` to `AccountType`

sources: [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)

Comment: thank you jason for the thorough answer. however, even with those changes, it still throws the same error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: accounttype`

Answer (score 0):

You should look into resource nesting and for nested resources use

```
accept_attributes_for :accounttype
```

http://masonoise.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/rails-and-forms-using-accepts_nested_attributes_for/

Comment: thanks for the answer @pavel, did you mean to leave out "nested" from that?

Comment: @Kristian you should also inspect your params to have attributes for accounttype , eg `params[:company][:accounttype_name]`